# How to change asp button color when disabled, by default button will be disabled on UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save" 
     CssClass="buttonNormal buttonChange" OnClick="submit_Click" 
     Enabled="false" ToolTip="Please click on the left button to enable save" />
```

On startup save button will be rendered as disabled, on click of other button, the "Save" button will be enabled.

Functionality is working as expected, but there is no difference in button view whether it's enabled or disabled.

Cannot write the color change logic in CS file because this button will be rendered on start of application.

Can someone help with this issue?

TIA,
Kal.

Answer (score 0):

In your submit_Click function, you could add;

```
using System.Drawing;
...
if(btnSubmit.Enabled == "False"){
   btnSubmit.BackColor = Color.Blue; // or btnSubmit.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
}
else{
   btnSubmit.BackColor = Color.Grey; // or btnSubmit.BackgroundColor = Color.Grey;
}
```

You can initially set the color like this;

```
<asp:Button BackgroundColor="Blue" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save" 
     CssClass="buttonNormal buttonChange" OnClick="submit_Click" 
     Enabled="false" ToolTip="Please click on the left button to enable save" />
```

Comment: It won't call submit_Click function On start of the application. so this won't work.

Comment: @kal but you can still initially set the color

Comment: '<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="buttonNormal buttonChange" OnClick="Submit_Click" Enabled="false" ToolTip="Please click on left button to enable save option" BackColor="#5b74a8" />'